# Get Values from collection Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

I have got a collection

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => / [pageTitle] => Something [pageViews] => 66 ) ) )
```

How can I get the pageTitle and pageViews from this collection?

Comment: use `first()` then use `->` tho access the properties

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the first record of your collection first and then you can access its properties.

```
$my_collection = $my_collection->first();

//then you can do
$my_collection->pageTitle;
//or
$my_collection->pageViews;
```

In case it gives you `can not read property of non-object` take the properties as an array

```
$my_collection = $my_collection->first();

//then you can do
$my_collection['pageTitle'];
//or
$my_collection['pageViews'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I solved it.

```
foreach($my_collection as $key){ $key['pageTitle']}
```